# Complex IF Statement multiple sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I hope you can help.

What I am trying to achieve is this. On my workbook I have many sheets. The sheet I want my answer on is **Vetplan_ROI_V6.** and I want the value to appear in column AC
The Formula I have type in AC is something like the below. But I am not getting the correct result. 
On sheet **Vetplan_ROI_V6**. IF Cell H2 = "57514" and Cell AB2 = "XLVets" then go to sheet named **ROI RUBU Schema** get the value in Cell G96 and multiply the figure in **Vetplan_ROI_V6** Cell M2 by the G96 value on **ROI RUBU Schema** and return me a numerical value.

The formula I have tried is `=IF(AND(H2="57514",AB2="XLVets",M2*'ROI RUBU Schema'!G96))`

I believe I should get a numerical result on line 400 from pic 1 but I just get FALSE

I am sure it something simple. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Pic 1

[image]

Pic 2
[image]

Comment: You aren't closing your AND. try `=IF(AND(H2="57514",AB2="XLVets"), M2*'ROI RUBU Schema'!G96, "")`

Comment: Adding to the comment from @Jeeped, from your screenshots, it looks like your call to `ROI RUBU Schema'!G96` should be absolute (it doesn't move when you, e.g., copy the cell or fill the formula down). Try this instead:
`=IF(AND(H2="57514",AB2="XLVets"),M2*'ROI RUBU Schema'!$G$96))`

Comment: ... or `=IF(AND(H2=57514, AB2="XLVets"), M2*'ROI RUBU Schema'!G$96, "")` since column H appears to have real numbers in it and not text-that-looks-like-a-number.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. The formula you gave worked perfectly. I the formatting was off and I needed to lock in the 96 part of G96. thank you so much for you help. Much respect from Dublin. I would like to accept your answer but don't see the icon. Please let me know if you an answer accepted. Again thank you for the help